What is the VBA code to save multiple pdf copies of individual sheets to separate locations on a computer
I am trying to save a pdf copy of spreadsheet sheet 1 in one location and a second pdf copy of spreadsheet sheet 2 in a second location in my documents, both would have the same file name based on data within 4 cells. I used the below script but can only get it to save a copy of the sheet 2 calculations in the correct location, if i try to save sheet 1 i get an error message.
Sub SaveAsPDF()


clientname = Range("A12")
quotenumber = Range("D4")
vehicle = Range("F11")
date = Range("G4")
Path = "/Users/bigbrother2/Documents/Quotations/Calculations/"
fName = clientname & " " & quotenumber & " " & vehicle & " " & date
MsgBox "Saved as PDF"
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, ignoreprintareas:=False,      FileName:=Path & fName

End Sub

Tried the above macro but it didnt work as expected

"i get an error message" is not a really useful description of what's going wrong when you run your code.  What is the specific error message, and on which line?

Instead of using ActiveSheet you just have to specify what sheets you want to export, for example:
Sub SaveSheetsAsPDF()
    Dim strClientName As String
    Dim strQuoteNumber As String
    Dim strVehicle As String
    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strPath1 As String
    Dim strPath2 As String
    
    ' Get the values for the file name
    strClientName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A12").Value
    strQuoteNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Value
    strVehicle = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F11").Value
    strDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G4").Value
    
    ' Define file name
    strFileName = strClientName & " " & strQuoteNumber & " " & strVehicle & " " & strDate
    
    ' Define paths
    strPath1 = "your\file\path\"
    strPath2 = "your\file\path2\"
    
    ' Save Sheet1 as PDF
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strPath1 & strFileName, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    MsgBox "Sheet1 saved as PDF in Details folder"
    
    ' Save Sheet2 as PDF
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strPath2 & strFileName, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    MsgBox "Sheet2 saved as PDF in Calculations folder"

    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Export Failed"
End Sub

